# Angular 2: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular

I got this message when I used the two-way binding [(ngModel)]

```
Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```

I understand that importing the FormsModule is suppose to fix this issue as many people got here. However, I did had the FormsModule imported but it doesn't help, issue still be there

Definitely there is something else get wrong with my code. Can you shed a light.
Here is my app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ValidationModule } from './validation/validation.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.module.routing';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ValidationModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 

}
```

here is my app.routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'

import { Home1Component } from './home1.component';
import { Home2Component } from './home2.component';

const appRoutes = [
  { path: 'home1', component: Home1Component },
  { path: 'home2', component: Home2Component },
  { path: 'validation', loadChildren: './validation/validation.module#ValidationModule'}
];

@NgModule({
    declarations:[
        Home1Component,
        Home2Component
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    exports:[
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

and here is my html

```html
<h1> home 1 </h1>
<form>
    <input [(ngModel)]="currentHero.name">
    <button type="button" (click)="onOkClicked()">Ok</button>
</form>
```

I attach my source code here, I'm using angular-cli
[source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/trub70plk9eqoa3/myForms.7z?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use reactive forms than you need to add : ReactiveFormsModule

```
@NgModule({
    declarations:[
        Home1Component,
        Home2Component
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        ReactiveFormsModule, 
    ],
    exports:[
        RouterModule
    ]
})
```

Comment: that's weird, but yours is exactly the answer, in my example the FormsModule need to be imported in the routing module also while it was in the app module. Is this documented somewhere? can you pls give a quote?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `FormsModule` to imports in the module where you're using its directives:

```ts
@NgModule({
    declarations:[
        Home1Component,
        Home2Component
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        FormsModule, // <<<=== missing
    ],
    exports:[
        RouterModule
    ]
})
```